# Check if an item exists in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to check if a particular value exists in the main array.

[Example:](https://jsfiddle.net/0gx60cfy/2/)

```
var hideFilters = function() {
    var listCategoryId = ['1000014', '1000015', '1000016', '1000017', '1000018', '1000019', '1000021', '1000086'];

    var actualCategoryId = '1000018';

    if (actualCategoryId === listCategoryId) {
        console.log('is equal');
    } else {
        console.log('fuen... fuen...');
    }
};

hideFilters();
```

Comment: if(actualCategoryId.includes(actualCategoryId))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(listCategoryId.indexOf(actualCategoryId) != -1) {
  console.log('exists')
}
```

Comment: Yea. There it is.

Answer (score 2):

If [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns an index greater or equal 0, the array contains the specified element. Otherwise it will return -1:

```js
var hideFilters = function() {
  var listCategoryId = ['1000014', '1000015', '1000016', '1000017', '1000018', '1000019', '1000021', '1000086'];

  var actualCategoryId = '1000018';

  if (listCategoryId.indexOf(actualCategoryId) > -1) {
    console.log('is equal');
  } else {
    console.log('fuen... fuen...');
  }
};

hideFilters();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**

```js
var listCategoryId = ['1000014', '1000015', '1000016', '1000017', '1000018', '1000019', '1000021', '1000086'];

var actualCategoryId = '1000018';

if ($.inArray(actualCategoryId, listCategoryId) != -1) {
  console.log('exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you run that with `"1000014"` it would claim it doesn't exist because `$.inArray()` works like `.indexOf`

Comment: @vlaz fixed it.. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No worries. It caught me out, too (I started to write an answer but people posted before I was finished). I knew _of_ the `$.inArray` function, but (based on the name) I assumed it returns a boolean rather than an index...I blame jQuery for the confusion.

Comment: @vlaz true, the name sounds like it will return true or false, but what it returns is a index of the match.